# Custom sort with custom ResultScriptWebPart

Tags: 2013, search-results

I know in 2010 there was a way how to add custom sorting by Managed Property, it was obtaining data provider in overriden method and than just set the sort property and direction. However in 2013 I didnt find a way how to add custom sorting in code, i mean like inheriting the `ResultsScriptWebPart`. I found out event called `BeforeserializeToContent` which gives me `DataProviderScriptWebPart` and here Iam able to customize the query at least. So question is how to customize the sort order? Thanks.
P.S.: Not using querystring, thanks

Comment: Hi, so I found solution. There is property called DefaultAvailableSorts:ComplexResultSort[] and is marked as virtual, so just overriding it and providing custom array will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

so I found solution. There is property called `DefaultAvailableSorts:ComplexResultSort[]` and is marked as virtual, so just overriding it and providing custom array will do the job.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your code. Thanks, Balu